# Fitting a scikit learn nearest neighbor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dense TF - IDF matrix that looks like :

```
mat = [[0.0982332 0.08762 ... 0.032476]]
```

When I do a sklearn `NearestNeighbor` on this dense matrix I get the error below .

```
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=100, metric='euclidean', algorithm='ball_tree', leaf_size=50)
nn.fit(<the_dense_matrix>)
```

Error :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Not sure what the error is , none of the other suggestions on stack overflow worked for me.

Comment: shouldn't `leaf_size` be an `int`?

Comment: @shihab That's just a typo here , not in my code. I saw that I get this error when I use euclidean distance metric and happens at metric_params_